# Makefile change variable inside a loop

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

I am trying to change a variable inside a loop but I am failing with some errors. Here is the part of my makefile.

```
export CLOCK_PERIOD = 30;
syn_clock: 
    for number in 1 2 3 4 ; do \
        echo $$CLOCK_PERIOD; \
        echo $$number; \
        $$CLOCK_PERIOD = $$number; \
    done
```

The outcome of the `make syn_clock` is failing with the following lines:

```
bash-4.2$ make syn_clock
for number in 1 2 3 4 ; do \
        echo $CLOCK_PERIOD; \
        echo $number; \
        $CLOCK_PERIOD = $number; \
done
30
1
/bin/sh: line 3: 30: command not found
30
2
/bin/sh: line 3: 30: command not found
30
3
/bin/sh: line 3: 30: command not found
30
4
/bin/sh: line 3: 30: command not found
make: *** [syn_clock] Error 127
```

I am expecting the `CLOCK_PERIOD` to change from 1 to 4 during the loop cycle.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shell syntax uses "FOO=42" not "$FOO=42". The line assigning CLOCK_PERIOD has a $ at the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already suggested in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47625314/makefile-change-variable-inside-a-loop#comment82208606_47625314), when assigning to a variable in the Bash shell, remove the spaces surrounding the assignment operator and the trailing `$` in the name of the variable to be assigned. That is, `CLOCK_PERIOD=$$number` instead of `$$CLOCK_PERIOD = $$number`.

Since `export CLOCK_PERIOD = 30;` in your Makefile will be run by `make`, and not the shell, the result may not be what you expect (the value of `CLOCK_PERIOD` will be `30;` instead of `30`). So, I also removed the trailing semicolon as suggested in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47625314/makefile-change-variable-inside-a-loop/47627743?noredirect=1#comment82224062_47627743).

The proposed solution is:

```
export CLOCK_PERIOD = 30
syn_clock: 
    for number in 1 2 3 4 ; do \
        echo $$CLOCK_PERIOD; \
        echo $$number; \
        CLOCK_PERIOD=$$number; \
    done
```

---

The first `$` in the double `$` of `$$number` is actually related to the Makefile: it is for escaping the second `$` inside the Makefile, so that the shell receives a `$`, otherwise, if just `$number` were written, `make` would interpret it as `${n}umber`, i.e.: `make` would expand the value of the variable `n` and this result would be concatenated with `umber`. That would be what the shell would receive.

Comment: `export CLOCK_PERIOD=30;` is make syntax, you can put as many spaces as you wish around the `=` operator, it will work the same. Moreover, the trailing semi-colon is probably not what the OP really wanted. So `export CLOCK_PERIOD=30` or `export CLOCK_PERIOD = 30` would be both fine (and better without the trailing `;`)

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Thanks a lot, I overlooked the fact that `export CLOCK_PERIOD=30;` is being actually run by `make`. Your are right too about the semicolon: it will be simply assigned to `CLOCK_PERIOD` producing `30;` instead of `30`.